# Registering a Marriage in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom

I'm Indian and will be getting married to my Romanian boyfriend in India. He is currently working in Winchester, England and that's where we plan to stay together after we are married. That's why we would like to get the marriage registered in UK.

So can anyone please guide me as to what are the procedures to carry out the same? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a service where it was possible to lodge copies of foreign marriage certificates with the GRO, but this [has now been discontinued](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/marriage-certificate-registry-service-discontinued-for-overseas-brits), and was only ever for UK citizens in the first place.

The UK government will recognise a foreign marriage, given a few basic requirements, such as:

1. The marriage is legal under local law
2. Both parties have capacity to marry according to the laws of their country of domicile (i.e. are of age) and any previous marriages have been legally terminated (i.e. by divorce) in the eyes of the UK.
3. You can provide proof of the marriage in the form of a marriage certificate or equivalent (if not already in English, then you will need some sort of certified translation)